# Isolating and filtering results from .most_common() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using the most_common() function imported from the collections module to show the most common letters in a string but have come across a few problems which I don't know how to solve.

```
import collections
from collections import Counter

message = "Hello, how are you today?   "
common = Counter(message).most_common(3)

print (common)
```

What I don't understand how to do is:

Filtering the final output so that the 3 most_common characters are letters and not things like space or apostrophe.

Getting the 3 most common letters by themselves (make it equal to a variable) so I can use it separately, I've tried doing this in the code below but it didn't work so i'm out of ideas.

```
import collections
from collections import Counter

message = "Hello, how are you today?   "
common = Counter(message).most_common(3)
firstletter = Counter(message).most_common(1)[0][0]
print(firstletter)
print (common)
```

For the 2nd problem i've been temporarily doing this:

```
common = Counter(message.replace(" ", "")).most_common(3)
```

but its clearly not going to work in the long term and its ridiculous to do replace with everything.

Comment: How about not counting the apostrophe or spaces ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method for you would be to not count anything that is not a characters -

```
common = Counter(m for m in message if m.isalpha()) \
                .most_common(3)
```

The above would only count the alphabets in the string , if you want it count digits as well , a simple way would be to use [`str.isalnum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) instead of [`str.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) .

Demo -

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> message = "Hello, how are you today?   "
>>> common = Counter(m for m in message if m.isalpha()) \
...                 .most_common(3)
>>> common
[('o', 4), ('e', 2), ('y', 2)]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, Thankyou!

Comment: @Aslinnl Glad I could be helpful! :-) . If you feel the answer was helpful, I would like to request you to consider accepting the answer (by clicking on the tick mark on the left side of the answer, so that it becomes green) , it would be helpful for the community.

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem, you can use `isalpha()` on your string before getting the most common elements. Just remove any non-letter characters.

Solve the first problem, and I guess your second problem will be solved too.